# Dynamically change state value according to `react` array key value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

It seems like it would be easy, but I don't know

`{Info.seedShapeDisplayText} -> one two three four ..` 
`one onClick <div> Hi Number Minsu, Bar : 1 </div>`
`two onClick <div> Hi Number Jenny, Bar : 3 </div>`

In summary, when 'one li tag text' is clicked, the div will output '{NumberStatus}' value corresponding to 'one text', and `{functionInfolabels}` corresponding value.

Click on the first button
I want to print the first array values ​​Minsu and 1.
How would you like to write code?

```
let functionInfolabels = ProductDetail && ProductDetail.chart?.functionalsInfo?.[0].materialsInfo?.[0].ingredientsInfo?.map(array => array.ingredientDisplayText);
console.log(functionInfolabels) // Array( 1,3,124 ..)

let NumberStatus = ProductDetail && ProductDetail.chart?.functionalsInfo?.[0].materialsInfo?.[0].ingredientsInfo?.map(array => array.chartStatus) 
console.log(NumberStatus) // Array ( Minsu, Jenny, Youngmin, ...)    


return (
          {ProductDetail && ProductDetail.chart?.functionalsInfo?.length ? 
            ProductDetail.chart?.functionalsInfo.map(Info => (
            <li key={Info.id}>{Info.seedShapeDisplayText}</li>
            )) : <li>There is not</li>}

// {Info.seedShapeDisplayText} -> one two three four .. 
// one onClick <div> Hi Number Minsu, Bar : 1 </div>
// two onClick <div> Hi Number Jenny, Bar : 3 </div>
....
<div>
Hi Number {NumberStatus} //  Minsu, Jenny,  Youngmin,  Jiho ...

<Bar 
labels={functionInfolabels} // 1,  3, 124 .... 
/>
</div>


)
```

Comment: Can you clean this up and ask again please?

Comment: @RobertRocha Click on the first button
I want to print the first array values ​​Minsu and 1.

Comment: @RobertRocha // JSON data is formed in this format. 
 chart:   
   functionalInfo: Array(5)   
      0: 
         materialsInfo: Array(1)  
         0:  
            igredientsInfo: Array(1)  
            0:  
             chartStatus: "minsu" 
             ingredientDisplayText:1
         
     1: 
          materialsInfo: Array(1)  
         0:  
            igredientsInfo: Array(1)  
        
            1:
             chartStatus: "Jeeny"
             ingredientDisplayText:3
             ...

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just add on `onClick` to your `<li>` element?

```
<li key={Info.id} onClick={() => setStateValue(Info.id)}> ...
```

Comment: Click on the first button
I want to print the first array values ​​Minsu and 1.

Comment: So `NumberStatus` is reliant upon the `Info.Id` that you set? I'm afraid your code is confusing me. How does the `Info.Id` relate?

Comment: the confusion here is in understanding how `Info.Id` associates to your overall `ProductDetails`. Since we can't see a sample object, it really is difficult to understand what it is you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: // JSON data is formed in this format. 
 chart:   
   functionalInfo: Array(5)   
      0: 
         materialsInfo: Array(1)  
         0:  
            igredientsInfo: Array(1)  
            0:  
             chartStatus: "minsu" 
             ingredientDisplayText:1
         
     1: 
          materialsInfo: Array(1)  
         0:  
            igredientsInfo: Array(1)  
        
            1:
             chartStatus: "Jeeny"
             ingredientDisplayText:3
             ...